# What is more efficient: new mesh with cloned material or cloned mesh with cloned material?

Tags: three.js

For a large number of objects (graph nodes in my case) which all have same geometry but different color, what is more efficient:

1) creating a mesh and then cloning the mesh and material of the mesh (with mesh.traverse) for each node

2) create new mesh with cloned material for each node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference between an object creation via `new` and `.clone()` is that the latter one also copies all properties from the source object. If you don't need this, it's better to just create your meshes via the `new` operator.

Since you have large number of objects, you might want to consider to use instanced rendering in order to reduce the amount of draw calls in your application. Right now, you have to draw each node separately. With instanced rendering, the nodes are drawn all at once. There are a couple of examples that demonstrate instanced rendering with `three.js`:

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=instancing

Using instanced rendering is not a must but it can be helpful if you run into performance issues. Another option which is easier to implement but less flexible is to merge all meshes into a large single geometry and use vertex colors. You will have a single geometry, material and mesh object but an additional vertex color attribute will ensure that your nodes are colored differently.

`three.js R103`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Maybe I should mention that I am using a js library (https://github.com/vasturiano/3d-force-graph) which depends on three.js and thus I can't really affect when and how nodes can be drawn. I can only specify mesh for each node.
Based on your comment I will just create new mesh with cloned material.